# S3GetObjectMetadataResponse Error, Crashes. How can I check it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, sdk

I have an app that builds a dynamic list of files to be downloaded, using the Amazon S3 iOS SDK. No matter where in the queue I start the downloading from, the same file consistently crashes the application.

I've pinpointed the problem using breaks, and it's coming from my S3GetObjectMetadataResponse line as I attempt to get the size of the file before downloading, for the sake of configuring the progress bar.

```
self.S3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" withSecretKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];    
S3GetObjectMetadataRequest *getMetadataRequest = [[S3GetObjectMetadataRequest alloc] initWithKey:self.file.fileName withBucket:[self.file contentURLBucket]];
S3GetObjectMetadataResponse *metadataResponse = [self.S3 getObjectMetadata:getMetadataRequest];
```

If I comment out the last line, everything works as intended - except for the progress bar, of course.

What can I do to handle S3GetObjectMetadataResponse errors? Is there a better way I can check the file size before downloading?

Thanks!

Comment: Are exceptions enabled in the SDK? Have you tried either adding a @try/@catch or disabling exceptions? See this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-Exceptions-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) for context.

Comment: @BobKinney That blog post had the answers and it seems to have done the trick! I'm able to see which files have problems being downloaded and why. Thanks! If you turn this into an answer I'll gladly accept it. And I guess I should check the AWS Blogs a bit more huh? Thanks!

Comment: @BobKinney  what is the safe thing to do , is it to  enable exception or disable, i encounter the same thing when retrieving checksum from uploaded file , it doesnt happen everytime

Comment: @Mr.G You may want to consider upgrading to version 2 of the SDK. It was updated to not use exceptions and be asynchronous by default.

Comment: @BobKinney thanks for your reply, i have already implemented V2 but there is another branch and i have to deal with it in V1 dev, i'll not use exceptions  and asynchronous call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you'll want to ensure that either exceptions are disabled in the [AWS SDK for iOS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) or that you use a `@try/@catch` block in your code around synchronous calls when using the SDK.

[This post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-Exceptions-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) on our blog explains how to disable exceptions and how to work with the SDK when exceptions are disabled.

[This post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2XVU3IRV1HBOJ/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Asynchronously-Part-I-Sync-vs-Async) is the first in a series that explains the various methods for using the SDK asynchronously. It is worth noting that if you make asynchronous requests with exceptions enabled you don't need the `@try/@catch` blocks.